# Density of continuous functions with compact support in weak $L^1$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

One can prove that the space of continuous functions with compact support is dense in $L^p$. But is it also dense in $L^{1,\infty}$ (or $L^{p,\infty}$)? I am not able to come up with a counter-example but if there should be one, it would involve $f(x) = \frac{1}{|x|^{n/p}}$ since this does not belong to $L^p$ but is in $L^{p,\infty}$.

Comment: What is $L^{p, \infty}$ ? And strong convergence implies weak convergence

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Weak_Lp

Comment: Using the notation in the wiki page, if $ f \in L^{p,\infty}$ then $\lambda_{f} (t) \le \frac{c}{t^p}$ for some $c > 0$ (for every $t > 0$).

Comment: So the topology is given by a quasi-norm which is basically the infimum of all such constants $c > 0$.

Comment: Do you mean the topology given by [this "quasi-norm"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_space#Definition) $\|f\|_{p,\infty}^p = \sup_{t>0} \, t^p\|1_{|f(x)| > t}\|_{L^1}$

Comment: Yes. And by this, you can show that $L^p$ is a subset of $L^{p,\infty}$.

Comment: Show that $f 1_{|x| < n} \to f$ in this topology, and use that $f 1_{|x| < n}$ is in $L^1_{loc}$ to solve the continuity

Comment: I am sorry but I don't get why this would be a counter-example.

Comment: I don't think $f 1_{|x|<n}$ is in $L_{\text{loc}}^1$. Consider $f(x) = 1/|x|$.

Comment: You mean the problem is if $p=1$ ? In that case with $f(x) = 1/x$ we have  $\lim_{t \to \infty}t \|1_{|f-g| > t}\|_{L^1}=\lim_{t \to \infty}t \|1_{|f| > t}\|_{L^1} = 2$ for any continuous function $g$. And it should work the same for $p \ne 1$. So you have your answer ?

Comment: I don't think I understand the argument fully. Can you please write this as an answer, if only for the case of weak $L^1$?